# Autorun Excel VBA script when outlook saves attachment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an outlook procedure that auto saves an excel attachment to a certain location on my hard drive.

I also have a VBA script in Excel that is designed to use the data from that file and send off emails to particular parties. Normally I would have to open the file and run the VBA script. Is there a way to have this VBA script auto-execute once the file is saved from outlook?

Answer (score 0):

The macro in the excel file won't run just because you have saved it.

However, you can run the macro by opening the workbook and calling the macro at `Workbook_Open` event

1.Open the workbook from outlook programatically

2.Let's say your macro procedure is `Sub runMe()` then you could write following function in Workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Call runMe
End Sub
```

3.After the macro is completed, close the workbook programatically.